# ojSelect after refresh shows blank instead of the first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jet

After refreshing the select list using: ***$(#selectId).ojSelect('refresh');*** , empty element (blank) is displayed on the UI instead of the first element. Only after clicking the dropdown, the elements are shown. I need the first element to be selected after the refresh is done.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I know its been long, but do you still have the code to reproduce this? My refresh doesn't display a blank value

Comment: Now its working fine. Thanks for the help.